# Recargar pestaña ajax desde un pop-up formulario

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo una página con pestañas y en una de ellas abro un pop-up de formulario con su correspondiente php para el procesado. Para recargar la página principal uso lo siguiente:

```
    echo "<script languaje='javascript' type='text/javascript'>location.reload();window.close();</script>";
```

Pero no consigo que me abra la pestaña correspondiente al punto de donde partí y debo abrirla manualmente:

```
            $j('#mytab').click(function(){
            $j.ajax(
                {
                url:'mytab.php',
                success: function(resultado6)
                {
                    $j('#destinob').html(resultado6);
                    $j.getScript('js/b.js');
                }
                }); 
                                         });
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: El problema es que actualizas la información recargando la página, con lo cual se cierra el modal. Cuando utilizamos ajax, lo hacemos para evitar recargar el navegar, deberías de plantearte cambiar la forma en que actualizas la información de la página principal.

Si pones algo más de información, puedo ponerte algún ejemplo.

Comment: Definitivamente usar window.reaload() no te sirve porque es como que presiones F5, NO entiendo por qué necesitas recargar la página en vez de simplemente cerrar el pop-up, podrías explicar mejor? gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias, quizá el problema es que tengo que cambiar el concepto. Ahora vengo de una página con ajax (mytab.php) que me abre un pop-up con dos archivos uno de formulario (formulario.php) y otro de procesamiento de datos (procesado.php). Por tanto están fuera de la página principal y no sé se si puedo pasar una variable para que me abra un tab en la página principal a través de la página de procesamiento. La verdad es que no sé como se hace eso. Quizá debería hacerlo todo en ajax pero precisamente era para no tener que cambiar la estructura que vengo manteniendo. Muchas gracias.